# Phantomjs hangs on resource heavy sites

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm not able to always get PhantomJS or phantomjs-node to run on resource-heavy sites. For example, I'm about 50% successful of requesting `http://www.huffingtonpost.com`. PhantomJS will usually hang on an ad request.

All networking examples in the PhantomJS documentation like netsniff.js, netlog.js, and confess.js seem to have the same issue.

I've tried a few things: setting a `resourceTimeout` value, and attempting some interval that checks elapsed time of a resource request and to abort if past a certain time. I haven't had any luck.

`resourceTimeout` seems to work only on occasion.

My code:

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function(page) {

    page.resources = [];

    page.set('settings.resourceTimeout', 800);
    page.set('settings.userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');

    page.set('onResourceTimeout', function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    })

    page.onResourceRequested(function(requestData, networkRequest) {},
                             function(req) {
      page.resources[req.id] = {
        request: req
      }
    })

    page.open('http://www.huffingtonpost.com', function(status) {

      if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log("Failed to load");
        ph.exit(1);
      }
      else {
        callback(page.resources);
        ph.exit();
      }
    })

  })
});
```

I've tried the following within the callback that has access to `networkRequest`:

```
var clock;
clearInterval(clock);

function check(){
  var current_time = new Date();
  var request_time = requestData.time;
  var diff = Math.abs(current_time - request_time);

  if (diff > 1500) {
    networkRequest.abort();
  };

}

clock = setTimeout(check, 2000);
```

The check seems to fails with `Error: cannot access member 'abort' of deleted QObject`.

I am trying to identify all resources, so I do not necessarily want to ignore any requests. Any ideas?

Comment: We had some serious problems with the 1.x offered PhantomJS binaries as well. We just cloned the repo and built Phantom on a Linux machine and compiled the 2.0.0 branch which was _much_ better. Since few days, you can finally get 2.0.0 binaries on http://phantomjs.org/. Did you try with this version?

Comment: @vanthome: Thanks! Great suggestion. I upgraded and the performance is noticeably better. It still hangs unfortunately about the same amount of times, with or without a timeout set. I've tried both on my own program and on the example netsniff.js. I'm curious if people have found a way around it.